# Is it possible to parry all melee attacks in PvP?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I'm practicing my parrying and notice, in PvP, that it's harder to parry the heavier weapons when wielded in two hands. Especially Ultra Greatswords and Maces I haven't yet been able to parry in PvP. Maybe I need to continue working on my timing, but it made me wonder:

**Dark Souls 3 PvP: Is it possible to parry all melee attacks?**

If not, which are the known melee weapons (or ways of attacking) that inhibit the opponent's option to parry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Whips cannot be parried.
- Jumping attacks from all weapons cannot be parried.
- Certain weapon skills cannot be parried. Generally, if it doesn't make sense to parry them they can't be (for example, Stomp).
- Two-handed great hammers, greataxes, ultra greatswords and curved greatsword generally cannot be parried.

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls3/comments/4hrzmy/guide_to_parryable_and_unparryable_weapons/) has a full list if you want to know specific skills and weapons.